# Discriminate between callers inside and outside class hierarchy

Tags: python, introspection

I have two classes `A` and `B`, where `B` inherits from `A` and overrides a property. `A` is not under my control so I cannot change it.

The code looks as follows:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value
    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = value

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super(B, self).__init__(value)
    @property
    def value(self):
        return super(B, self).value
    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
```

When I try to call `B(1)` I obviously get `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

I would like to have a different behaviour when `value` is set from inside class methods

```
 @value.setter
 def value(self, value):
     if set from inside class hierarchy:
         pass
     else:
         raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
```

The module `inspect` does not seem to give me enough information to do this, except checking against a list of known functions.

Comment: Can't you just set `self._value` instead of `self.value`? Properties exist as an API to the outside world, not necessarily for within the object itself.

Comment: You could inspect the stack trace to find out who the caller is.

Comment: @acdr, unfortunately `A` is not under my control so I cannot change the way it behaves. I have edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Norman, it would tell me the name of the function, but not what class it belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect the stack to determine who called, and whether that it's in the class hierarchy to decide whether or not to allow it:

```
import inspect


def who_called():
    frame = inspect.stack()[2][0]
    if 'self' not in frame.f_locals:
        return None, None
    cls = frame.f_locals['self'].__class__
    method = frame.f_code.co_name
    return cls, method

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = value

    # Assuming this existed it would also work
    def change_value(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

Class `B` now checking:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super(B, self).__init__(value)

    @property
    def value(self):
        return super(B, self).value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        cls, method = who_called()
        if cls in B.__mro__ and method in A.__dict__:
            self._value = value
        else:
            raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
```

Proof:

```
b = B('does not raise error')
b.change_value('does not raise error')
b.value = 'raises error'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code that made the call to determine whether the call came from inside the class. Only throw an exception if the call didn't start with `self.value =`.

```
import re
import traceback

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value
    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = value

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super(B, self).__init__(value)
    @property
    def value(self):
        return super(B, self).value
    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        call = traceback.extract_stack(limit=2)[0][3]
        if re.match(r'self.value\s*=', call):
            pass
        else:
            raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")

b = B(1) # OK
b.value = 3 # Exception
```

Of course, this breaks as soon as you start calling your variables `self`:

```
self = B(1) # OK
self.value = 3 # Meh, doesn't fail
```